# VBA- all data is copied instead of duplicate data

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in my workbook.
*EDIT: I figured the reason why the record didnt start at B8. I need to have the header.

Master Sheet

1. has header range of B7:Y7, records start at B8

Update Dups Sheet

1. duplicate data from Master sheet will be copied and pasted here.
2. has the same header range as Master Sheet, and records start at B8

I found the code here, and edited it to suits my data, however, instead of only copying the duplicate data, it copies all of the data. and delete only one instance of duplicate data. (Example: 4 duplicates, only delete 1). the data order is also inverted.

```
Sub tryagain()
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set Rng = Range("B3:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = Rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cells(i, "B")) > 1 Then
              lr = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
              Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lr)
              'Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The records also didn't start at B8 like intended. I've tried so many ways, and it seems like a dead end for me. Any helps from you are much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this what you are looking for? -> Save a table into a range, delete all records from that temporary range that are NOT duplicates, paste that range into another sheet.

Comment: hi @DavidG hrm. What i want is that, when i click on a button in fruit dups, i will display all the duplicate data from master sheet, and delete the duplicate in master sheet. This is because I want the user to see which record is being duplicate.

Comment: So: You want to copy only duplicates into another sheet, and then (same step?) delete duplicates in the main sheet. Correct?

Comment: @DavidG yes. or the deleting part can be done separately

Answer (score 0):

Try to do one step at a time:

1. Declare 2 ranges (A and B)
2. Copy your table from first sheet into the second sheet
3. Set data from sheet 1 to range A, data from sheet 2 to range B
4. [Remove all duplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) from A
5. [Remove all non duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672465/delete-non-duplicate-data-in-excel-using-vba) from B
6. Sort ranges

Comment: Hi David. Instruction 1 meaning that I declared the range into to variable right?

Comment: Declaring all needed variables would be step 0. Step 1 is copying all the needed data into a range object (as already done in your code on line 4). Check out [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html) step by step guide for working with range objects.

Comment: If my post helped you, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your help, as I am very new to vba, I am still struggling to do all the things that you mentioned. Once I succeed, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Can you add details on your exact problems? I might be able to help you further.